# Importing large chunks of data from XML and saving it into database using PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, import

Here is the scenario for what i am looking to accomplish.
Working on classified websites which need to take data from advertisers  in XML format and load that into there system each field in XML should be mapped to some field in database.

The XML contains CDATA, links which should be uploaded to the server by fetching them from the URL one item in XML may contain upto 20 images and there will be approximately 400 nodes.
Please suggest me a solution to get that file parsed by PHP without any time out error.

Previously i used SimpleLargeXMLParser class to get this done but it only uploads around 100 nodes and then server shows up 500 Internal server error.
Is there any definite solution to get this done?
Please Help

Comment: check the server's error log for details about the 500. If your script is long running, then it should **NOT** be running under a webserver. PHP invoked from the command line is not subject to the time limits.

Comment: I did that but there is no error found in it. Moreover when browser shows the 500 internal error the script run for some more time at the background and then stops.

Comment: It is probably you are selecting your nodes once. I have the same problem which an xml has 14k nodes. I aparted xml 2 part. Then begin import process. And It was successfully added 14k row to mysql. Try to chunk it when you importing nodes from xml. Simply limit your INSERT INTO or UPDATE statement and take nodes from xml to mysql 2 or 3 part.